# strip interval's (inconsistent) start and end date within a large data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame which consists of 2 columns.
Date  - Quarterly date
Indicator Value - Ranges from 1 to -1 for a given date.

```
Date(Quarter)   Indicator Value    

1872-12-31        0.5                  
1873-03-31       -0.2                  
1873-06-30       -0.15                 
1873-09-30        0.7                  
1873-12-31        0.4                  
1874-03-31        0.9                 
1874-06-30       -0.3                  
1874-09-30       -0.1                  
1874-12-31        0.8
```

I am interested in negative value cycle. I want to get the start and end date for all negative values but not individually. For example,

```
First one starts at 1873/01/01 and ends in 1873/06/30
The second one starts at 1874/04/01 and ends in 1874/09/30
```

I tried creating binary values. For example, all the positive will still have zero and the negative numbers will have 1. Then I can strip out smaller data frames and get the dates.

It seems like I am making this harder it looks.

```py
def f(row):
    if row['Indicator value'] < 0:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = 0
    return val

df['Binary Value'] = df3.apply(f, axis = 1)
```

Data frame looked liked this:

```
    Date(Quaterly)   Indicator Value    Binary Value 

1872-12-31        0.5                  0
1873-03-31       -0.2                  1
1873-06-30       -0.15                 1
1873-09-30        0.7                  0
1873-12-31        0.4                  0
1874-03-31        0.9                  0
1874-06-30       -0.3                  1
1874-09-30       -0.1                  1
1874-12-31        0.8                  0
```

I am kind of stuck after this. I don't know where to go from here.

I want to create a list of start and end dates

```
Start Date     End date 
1873/01/01     1873/06/30 
1874/04/01     1874/09/30
```

Comment: You are right that you are making your life harder. Also, what about the corner cases where the first date or last date has negative indicator value? What results do you expect then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g = (df['Indicator Value'].gt(0) == df['Indicator Value'].lt(0).shift()).cumsum()
g.name = 'value'

df = df.groupby(g).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[0:1, -1:0]])

allneg = df[df['Indicator Value'].lt(0)].reset_index().drop(columns = ['value','level_1'])

pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([allneg.loc[::2, 'Date(Quarter)'].values.reshape(-1,1), allneg.loc[1::2, 'Date(Quarter)'].values.reshape(-1,1)]))\
  .rename(columns = {0:'Start Date', 1:'End Date'})

    Start Date   End Date
0   1873-03-31  1873-06-30
1   1874-06-30  1874-09-30
```

g is the creation of groupings that we want for our Indicator Value column. The value goes up whenever the sign changes.

We then group by g, then apply a function that takes the first value and last value in each group (so if there are 3 or more neg values in a row it will only take the first and the last).

Next we filter out the positive values and do a little cleaning. Finally, we manipulate allneg to get just the starting and ending dates and make it a new dataframe.

For my start dates, I use the initial negative one, I'm not sure where you got yours from.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Date column represents the end date for each quarter. I want the start date for the initial negative one. For example, the first negative value corresponds to a quarter ending 1873-03-31. However, I want the start date of that quarter which is 1873-01-01. Apologies if I did not make that clear. I am still going through the code to see if I can do this myself. It would be helpful if you have a way alter the code. Thanks, again.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Thanks for the help.